# Views: How to filter content by taxonomy terms that are not selected?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view of a specific content type that can be filtered by two different taxonomies A and B. Some nodes that have the taxonomy term A1 also have the term B5. Now when I filter only by the term A2 I also want all the nodes to be listed that have both the term A1 AND B5, irrespective if B5 is selected or not. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: Is your referrring to "A2" a typo and you mean "A1"? Filters already work that way. You have to include details of your filters configuration, and relevant CTs and fields. Also your title is misleading, you're not actually looking for "not selected", you're looking for selected irrespective of other terms, I'm assuming in the same field?

Comment: No, it's how I meant it. Imagine there is database with doctors for adults (A1) and doctors for children (A2). Some doctors for adults (A1) also have a special permission to treat children (B5), but this option is not really understandable by ordinary people and they will rarely select it. So when they filter for childrens' doctors also the adult doctors that have this special permission shall be shown.